# Yahoo Rejecting Email - dkim=temperror (multiple keys)

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

Sorry this is long, I wanted to provide all the information I could.

We have a web based application that sends emails to people that request information.  Just recently Yahoo has been rejecting our messages.  We are getting this message from our server when an email is rejected.....

> : host
>   mx-biz.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[74.6.137.68]
>       said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04] Messages from 52.8.99.170 temporarily deferred due
>       to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see
>       https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL FROM
>       command)

Yahoo's postmaster help site says it's a temporary error and to keep trying to send the message.  We are but this is not working.

I've been in contact with Yahoo and they said our IP just started sending 1000s of messages.  Our volume is pretty low, so this is not true and we've had this IP for some time. I've also looked at the mail logs and we are not sending 1000s of messages. I investigated and it looks like our DKIM and SPF were not set up correctly.  So I have been working to correct this and using tools from....

- https://mxtoolbox.com/
- https://intodns.com

...to verify my DNS settings and all is ok with my DKIM and DNS settings. But our mail still is not reaching Yahoo mail users. So I think something is still wrong.

Using my Yahoo test account, I send a message to an account on our server and then reply to it as this seems to get the message back to Yahoo and allows me to look at the headers and authentication information.

Here is where I believe the problem is....

> Authentication-Results: mta4322.mail.gq1.yahoo.com 
>   from=sanitationmanager.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig); 
>   from=sanitationmanager.com; dkim=temperror (multiple keys)

**Does anyone have some insight on how to fix dkim=temperror (multiple keys)? As I believe if I fix this our other messages should reach the Yahoo recipients who request information.**

Here is part of the raw message that I get to go to my Yahoo test account....

```
X-Apparently-To: sanmansw22@yahoo.com; Thu, 09 Aug 2018 23:17:00 +0000 
Return-Path: <antonio@sanitationmanager.com> 
Received-SPF: pass (domain of sanitationmanager.com designates 52.8.99.170 as permitted sender) 
X-YMailISG: x2USG84WLDvAQzeKoE80QqOsPLx_DAK_Bdh8gtIi7vqIyiCl 
.......  
X-Originating-IP: [52.8.99.170] 
Authentication-Results: mta4322.mail.gq1.yahoo.com  from=sanitationmanager.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=sanitationmanager.com; dkim=temperror (multiple keys)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO mail.sanitationmanager.com) (52.8.99.170)  
  by mta4322.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with SMTP; Thu, 09 Aug 2018 23:16:59 +0000
Received: by mail.sanitationmanager.com (Postfix, from userid 1004)     
     id 8DB6C1209749; Thu,  9 Aug 2018 16:16:59 -0700 (PDT) 
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mail.sanitationmanager.com 8DB6C1209749 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=sanitationmanager.com; s=default; t=1533856619;
    bh=0zI/stfmBTNMI7cEQEoOgewqELaOKZD9UbuKxghyJsM=;     
    h=Date:To:Subject:From:From;     
    b=Nb1Bwx0sPOOukWsi0dvg+/c2PPhSJfoH3dtM6YHbmsZNU8sFFTZ5cwCZlVUlaJlTQ     
  k5APegJV3KqIQFWLEs8oYcWENzq1TNynQTk/HlFy1fJ/G+283CXaiGWWQux/P5J8aX    
  OpWeRXdzTH+ObgIKbHTCdMXdOE4rWV4lrDJAv92I= 
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2018 16:16:59 -0700
To: sanmansw22@yahoo.com 
Subject: Test from SanMan 
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 
Message-Id: <20180809231659.8DB6C1209749@mail.sanitationmanager.com> 
From: antonio@sanitationmanager.com 
Content-Length: 31

This is a message from Antonio
```

And here are my DNS settings at AWS Route53

[DNS settings at AWS Route53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP4cE.gif)

I am open to any suggestions, corrections, criticisms, etc. to help solve my issue and getting messages to the Yahoo recipients that request them.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check to make sure your server has not been compromised.

Comment: I don't think that is the case.  Anything is possible and I'd have to do a full diagnostics to confirm this, which I will, but I don't see anything that points to this.  I have updated packages frequently, sign on using a key, history show only logins from my IP, AWS firewall, local firewall, SE Linux, and no unknown daemons running.

Comment: And there's no web application running on the instance?

Comment: Yes, we have a few web applications running on this instance, they are not accessible to the public all require a  user/pass, but that's not full proof. I don't see any excessive usage over the past 6 months.  But you got me a little concerned and intrigued.  Is a compromise an indication of my initial question (dkim=temperror (multiple keys)?  How would a compromise be related to this error?

Comment: When a mail provider says they suddenly got thousands of messages, if that's not normal volume, it's a strong indicator of _something_. If you didn't actually send thousands of messages, then it's a strong indicator of compromise.

Comment: Sorry for the late following.  I was away for a wedding.  That was the odd thing coming from Yahoo, we do send around 1000+ messages per month and have been doing so for over a year.  They said their analysis (which they wouldn't reveal how they did it) showed we never send email and then all of the sudden we were sending 1000s of messages.  So I'm not sure I believe them.

Comment: Back to the main problem - what does dkim=temperror (multiple keys) really mean.  If it is truly an indication of a compromise I am curious.  And since I'm back, I'm doing an audit on that system.  Thanks.

Comment: I would like to answer this question myself, but I can't back them up with any concrete proof.   1) I don't think the server has been compromised.  Yahoo saying we just started sending 1000s of messages is false.  We've been sending messages for over a year.  I looked through all of the mail logs for the last month (spend a lot of time) and they were all legit messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question myself, but I can't back my points with concrete proof, but I'm going to answer it anyway.

1) I don't think the server has been compromised.  Yahoo saying we just started sending 1000s of messages is false.  We've been sending messages for over a year.  I looked through all of the mail logs for the last month (spent a lot of time) and they were all legit messages.
2) What I think happened is that someone with a Yahoo account asked for some information from us and then said it was spam and then it just snow balled from there. We couldn't send any messages to Yahoo without them being rejected.
3)  I showed Yahoo the DMARC report with the dkim=temperror (multiple keys) message and they say everything is working fine and gave no explanation of the error. Closed the case.
4) There has been a lot of undelivered messages and time wasted.

Comment: Actually it's pretty believable. Yahoo is pretty horrible as a mail provider. I have for years recommended that anyone who actually wants to get mail not use them.